# How to Get "_id" field value from kinvey.com

Tags: delphi, backend, delphi-xe6, kinvey

I been using kinvey.com, and every time I try to get `Manga._id` it returns null. Can you help me figure out why?

```
TManga = class
  strict private
    FSite,
    FManga,
    FID: String;
  published
    property Site        : string  read FSite        write FSite;
    property Manga       : string  read FManga       write FManga;
    property _id         : string  read FID          write FID;
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
var
  Mangas: TBackendObjectList<TManga>;
  Manga : TManga;
  QueryStr: TArray<string>;
  i: Integer;
begin
with xQuery do
  begin
    Execute;
    Mangas := TBackendObjectList<TManga>.Create;

    QueryStr := TArray<string>.Create('');

    xStorage.Storage.QueryObjects<TManga>('xxxx' ,QueryStr ,Mangas);

    with xListBox do
    begin
      Items.BeginUpdate;
      try
        Items.Clear;
        for I := 0 to Mangas.Count -1 do
        begin
          Manga := Mangas.Items[I];
          items.add(Manga.Site + ' - ' + Manga._id) // Manga._id this is everytime null 

        end;

      finally
        Items.EndUpdate;
      end;

    end;
  end;
```

http://i.hizliresim.com/M94QPN.png

Comment: Where is the code that actually creates the objects? Also what you could do is use `For Manga in Mangas do` That way you dont have to assign `mangasi.items[I]` to `Manga` every time. And do the other properties have correct values?

Comment: I have feeling that issue in 
xStorage.Storage.QueryObjects<TManga>('xxxx' ,QueryStr ,Mangas);
when, as I suppose, you fill data...

Comment: @TeunPronk thx for "For in clause". And other every properties true value but just Manga._id is everytime returned null.

Comment: @Zam "xStorage.Storage.QueryObjects<TManga>('xxxx' ,QueryStr ,Mangas)" do not specify a problem here or I can't find

Comment: @user3825157 if youre debugging will all properties be set properly? And can you post your code where you craete the objects? You dont see a problem in the code but maybe others do :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the value 'fields=_id' in one of the array elements of QueryStr?

Comment: You would probably need to add the other fields as well, to prevent them being null

Comment: I'm sorry, but I actually wanted to add it as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your column _id is always null because the Kinvey API doesn't get the _id column as a simple column but as the object ID of the record.
In order to get the object ID of your Manga record, you must to add a variable like this:

```
  oEntity: TBackendEntityValue;
```

So right under this line in the "for" statement:

```
  Manga := Mangas.Items[I];
```

You may add these two new lines:

```
oEntity := FBackendList.EntityValues[Manga]; // Gets the Kinvey object
Manga._id := oEntity.ObjectID; // Sets the _id property of the current TManga instance
```

One important thing you may take in mind is when you will add new records in your Kinvey collection. You don't have to write in the _id property of your new TManga item before you create your new record. However you will need to get it from Kinvey right after you insert the new record.
This code was adapted from the Embarcadero's ToDo sample:

```
procedure TDataModule1.AddBackendItem(const AItem: TManga);
var
  oEntity: TBackendEntityValue;
begin

  // After the execution of this command the new record will be inserted in Kinvey, and the variable oEntity will get the respective object ID 
  BackendStorage1.Storage.CreateObject<TManga>(
    TMangaNames.BackendClassname, AItem, oEntity);

  AItem._id := oEntity.ObjectID; // Updates the property _id of the current instance of TManga

  FBackendList.Add(AItem, oEntity);

end;
```

I hope it can help you!